# calculate number of days left in an year from specific date using mysql

Tags: mysql, date

How to calculate the number of difference between a specific date to the current year last date.
Consider I would like to show date difference between 2009-09-01 to current year last date(2010-12-31)

Comment: Just a question: Why do you need to calculate this in MySQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`to_days`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_to-days):

```
select to_days(concat(year(now()),'-12-31')) - to_days(now()) as days_left;
+-----------+
| days_left |
+-----------+
|       121 |
+-----------+
```

or use [datediff](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) like this

```
select datediff(concat(year(now()),'-12-31'), now()) as days_left;
+-----------+
| days_left |
+-----------+
|       121 |
+-----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

use datediff function:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Answer (score 0):

mysql have a function for everything.
One you need in this particular case is TO_DAYS()